# Java do while Guessing Game

Tags: java

So for an assignment I had to do last week I had to make a guessing game in Java using 4 do-while loops and if statements. I was unable to complete it successfully and the class has moved on providing me no help. I would appreciate it if someone could look at my code and tell me where I could improve it so the program works properly.

To give a brief description of the assignment, the assignment calls for 4 do-while loops:

1. The primary do-while loop which contains most of the code and keeps
   the program running until the user wants to quit
2. The game do-while loop which keeps the game running until the user
   guesses the correct number, at which point it will exit. (This part
   I could not figure out).
3. A numeric input validation do-while loop inside of the game loop,
   which makes sure the user's guess is valid.
4. A non-numeric input validation do-while loop which is after and
   outside of the game loop that asks the user if they want to play
   again, and checks for a valid 'Y' or 'N' response

Here is what I came up with:

```
package week4;

//Imports
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab4d {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set up scanners
        Scanner again = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner num1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Set up variables
        int userInput = 0;
        int guesses = 0;
        int min = 1;
        int max = 100;
        int range = max - min + 1;
        int randNum = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
        boolean valid = false;

        //Outside loop
        do{
            //Describe the game
            System.out.println("\nThis program is a guessing game.");
            System.out.println("\nThe computer will pick a random number "
                               + "between 1 and 100.");
            System.out.println("\nYou will try to guess it.");
            System.out.println("\nLet's play!");

            //Insert Game loop here
            do {
                System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number " +
                                   "between 1 and 100.");
                //Insert valid guess checker here
                do {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
                    if (num1.hasNextInt()){
                        userInput = num1.nextInt();
                        valid = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a whole number.\n");
                        num1.nextLine();
                    }
                }while(!valid);

                if (userInput > randNum) {
                    System.out.println("\nToo high!");
                    guesses++;
                }
                else if (userInput < randNum) {
                    System.out.println("\nToo Low!");
                    guesses++;
                }
                else if (userInput == randNum) {
                    System.out.println("You got it!");
                    System.out.println("It took you" + guesses + "tries");
                    valid = true;
                }
            }while(!valid);


            //Insert play again checker
            do {
                System.out.println("\nDo you want to play again?");
                System.out.println("\nEnter 'Y' if yes and 'N' if no.");
                String play = again.nextLine();
                if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    valid = true;
                }
                else if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    valid = true;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Please answer with 'Y' or 'N'");
                }
            }while(!valid);

        }while(!valid);
    }
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //you only need one

int userInput = 0;
int guesses = 0;
int min = 1;
int max = 100;
int range = max - min + 1;
int randNum = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
boolean valid = false;
boolean playAgain = false;

do {
  System.out.println("\nThis program is a guessing game.");
  System.out.println("\nThe computer will pick a random number between 1 and 100.");
  System.out.println("\nYou will try to guess it.");
  System.out.println("\nLet's play!");

  do {
    System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
    do {
      System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
      if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
        userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        valid = true;
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a whole number.\n");
        scanner.nextLine();
        userInput = -1; //this is important
        valid = false;
      }
    } while(!valid);

    if (userInput == randNum) {
      System.out.println("You got it!");
      System.out.println("It took you " + guesses + " tries");
      valid = true;
    }
    else {
      valid = false; //this is important
      ++guesses;
      if (userInput > randNum) {
        System.out.println("\nToo high!");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("\nToo Low!");
      }
    }
  } while(!valid);

  do {
    System.out.println("\nDo you want to play again?");
    System.out.println("\nEnter 'Y' if yes and 'N' if no.");
    String play = scanner.nextLine();

    if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
      valid = true;
      playAgain = true;
    }
    else if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
      valid = true;
      playAgain= false;
    }
    else {
      valid = false;
      System.out.println("Error: Please answer with 'Y' or 'N'");
    }
  } while(!valid);
} while(playAgain);

scanner.close();
```

But, I suggest using more functions (especially for the inner for loops) to keep your code managable and more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part of the program

```
//Insert Game loop here
        do {
            System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number " +
                    "between 1 and 100.");
            //Insert valid guess checker here
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
                if (num1.hasNextInt()){
                    userInput = num1.nextInt();
                    valid = true; //>>>>> HERE YOU SET VALID TO TRUE 
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Please enter a whole number.\n");
                    num1.nextLine();

                }

            }while(!valid);
            if (userInput > randNum) {
                System.out.println("\nToo high!");
                guesses++;
            }
            else if (userInput < randNum) {
                System.out.println("\nToo Low!");
                guesses++;
            }
            else if (userInput == randNum) {
                System.out.println("You got it!");
                System.out.println("It took you" + guesses + "tries");
                valid = true;
            }

        }while(!valid); //>>>>> AND THIS !VALID CHECK USES THE SAME "valid" boolean
```

So just use two separate booleans
like so

```
//Imports
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4d{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set up scanners
    Scanner again = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner num1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Set up variables
    int userInput = 0;
    int guesses = 0;
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
    boolean valid = false;

    // Outside loop
    do {
        // Describe the game
        System.out.println("\nThis program is a guessing game.");
        System.out.println("\nThe computer will pick a random number " + "between 1 and 100.");
        System.out.println("\nYou will try to guess it.");
        System.out.println("\nLet's play!");

        // Insert Game loop here
        do {
            System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number " + "between 1 and 100.");
            // Insert valid guess checker here

            boolean userInputValid = false;
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
                if (num1.hasNextInt()) {
                    userInput = num1.nextInt();
                    userInputValid = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Please enter a whole number.\n");
                    num1.nextLine();
                }
            } while (!userInputValid);

            if (userInput > randNum) {
                System.out.println("\nToo high!");
                guesses++;
            } else if (userInput < randNum) {
                System.out.println("\nToo Low!");
                guesses++;
            } else if (userInput == randNum) {
                System.out.println("You got it!");
                System.out.println("It took you" + guesses + "tries");
                valid = true;
            }

        } while (!valid);

        // Insert play again checker
        do {
            System.out.println("\nDo you want to play again?");
            System.out.println("\nEnter 'Y' if yes and 'N' if no.");
            String play = again.nextLine();
            if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

                valid = true;
            }

            else if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {

                valid = true;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Error: Please answer with 'Y' or 'N'");
            }

        } while (!valid);

    } while (!valid);
}
```

}

Just as an info (not directly related to your question), be careful comparing Integers with "==", it only works for values from -128 up to 127.
(but you can use == for primitive type "int")

https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two Scanner objects. You can do the entire application with a single Scanner object:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Your variables **guesses**, **randNum**, and **valid** should be ***initialized*** within the main game loop. This way, when a new game starts, a new random value (**randNum**) is acquired, **valid** is reset to boolean false, and **guesses** is reset to **0**.

The `valid = true;` located within the `if (num1.hasNextInt()){ ... }` **IF** code block of the `Please enter your guess:` prompt loop should be removed (deleted). This is to soon to say the input is valid and allows the prompt loop to exit. This flag should **only** fall true if a correct value which matches the generated **randNum** value is supplied by the User.

Your **IF** statements for checking User input should be contained within the `Please enter your guess:` prompt loop. This allows the indicators **Too High** or **Too Low** to be displayed and the `Please enter your guess:` prompt to be re-displayed for another guess.

The **guesses** variable is keeping an incorrect count (not enough). You only need one `guesses++;` and it should be placed directly after the User entry validity check **IF/ELSE** blocks.

You should set **valid** to false **before** entering the `Do you want to play again?` prompt loop.

In your `Do you want to play again?` prompt loop you set **valid** to **true** if either **Y** or **N** is supplied. So the main game loop is never passed through again. Because you are using the **valid** boolean variable as a condition for **all** your loops you will want to ensure that if **Y** (yes) is supplied then **valid** meets the condition required to re-loop the main game loop (which happens to be boolean false) or use a different boolean flag for this main game loop (perhaps: `boolean playAgain = false;`). Currently, if **Y** is supplied then **valid** should equal **false** and a **break;** ought to be issued so as to exit the prompt loop. Because **valid** is false the main game loop iterates again for a new game. If **N** is supplied then simply exit the game at this point. There is no need to just exit the prompt loop:

```
 else if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing...Bye Bye");
    System.exit(0);
 }
```

Placing the:

```
System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number "
                 + "between 1 and 100.");
```

within a **do/while** loop is pointless. Keep the output to console but remove the **do {** and **} while(!valid);**.

Alternative code might look something like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//Set up variables
int userInput = 0;
int guesses;
int min = 1;
int max = 100;
int range = max - min + 1;
int randNum;
boolean valid;
boolean playAgain = false;

//Outside loop
do {
    //Describe the game
    System.out.println("\nThis program is a guessing game.");
    System.out.println("\nThe computer will pick a random number "
            + "between 1 and 100.");
    System.out.println("\nYou will try to guess it.");
    System.out.println("\nLet's play!");

    randNum = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
    valid = false;
    guesses = 0;

    //Insert Game loop here
    System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number "
            + "between 1 and 100.");
    //Insert guess and validator here
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            userInput = input.nextInt();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: Please enter a whole number.\n");
            input.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        guesses++;
        if (userInput > randNum) {
            System.out.println("\nToo high!");
        }
        else if (userInput < randNum) {
            System.out.println("\nToo Low!");
        }
        else if (userInput == randNum) {
            System.out.println("You got it!");
            System.out.println("It took you " + guesses + " tries");
            valid = true;
        }
    } while (!valid);

    //Insert play again checker
    valid = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("\nDo you want to play again?");
        System.out.println("\nEnter 'Y' if yes and 'N' if no.");
        String play = input.nextLine();
        if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            playAgain = true;
            valid = playAgain;
        }
        else if (play.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            playAgain = false;
            valid = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: Please answer with 'Y' or 'N'");
        }
    } while (!valid);
} while (playAgain);

System.out.println("Thanks for playing...Bye Bye");
```

**To Do:** Allow the User to Quit at any time.